# eclipse not accepting my eclipsified todolist application

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0, osx-mountain-lion

I am new to play. So naturally I am starting out with [the scala `todolist` tutorial on the official website](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTodoList). But since I want to do the work on eclipse, I am also using [this tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/ide) to `eclipsify` my project. So I did this

```
play new todolist
play eclipsify todolist
```

Then when I try to import the project by doing: `File >> import >> general >> existing project into workspace` and then point to my project as `myPath/todolist`, eclipse complained that `No projects are found to import`. Any help please?

---

EDIT:

My hunt led me to this tutorial (http:// scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play20scalaide20/index.html). So I `cd` into `todolist` and start `play`. Then when I type `eclipsify` I get the error:

```
[todolist] $ eclipsify
[error] Not a valid command: eclipsify (similar: eclipse)
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: eclipsify
[error] eclipsify
[error]          ^
```

Comment: `Not a valid command: eclipsify (similar: eclipse)` - have you investigated what `eclipse` does?

Comment: @Luigi Plinge I am not even embarrassed to say thank you. Do you mind posting as answer so I may accept?

Comment: By the way, you are likely using Play 2.1, not 2.0. And the Scala IDE tutorial is for Play 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eclipsify` has been replaced by `eclipse` in recent versions of sbt, so use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

play eclipse |app name|

Creates the files needed to use the eclipse IDE.

Comment: Please provide a little more detail and content. It doesn't answer the question in enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the eclipse project that can be imported so, you have to do : "eclipse" command after "sbt"

and then try to import it should work.